# How to generate a PDF form that can be used in both Mac Preview and Adobe Reader?

Tags: pdf, adobe, pdf-generation, preview, pdf-form

I previously had an Elance contractor generate a PDF form for me to use for invoicing purposes.

I like the form, but I only can open it using Adobe Reader(Mac) and not Preview.

Recently, I came across a form that can be opened and filled in using Preview AND Adobe Reader.

See [here](http://cl.ly/Fx0d)

My question is, how do I generate a PDF form that can be opened in both Preview and Adobe Reader?

I am asking for both:

- manual generation (using a software or an application like Word or
  Adobe Professional PDF)
- programatically (using code or library,
  preferably open source)

Comment: Check out this post that might help you, http://www.assuredynamics.com/index.php/2011/02/pdf-forms-in-apple-preview/

Comment: I read that post. But the bottom says to have a piece of text to say, Please use Adobe Reader to open this form. Which is not ideal. This is the form I was previously talking about. http://cl.ly/Fx0d  It works in both Preview and in Adobe Reader which is great.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main types of PDF forms, [AcroForms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acroforms#Interactive_elements), and [XFA forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFA). Although I have not tested this, I suspect that if you want a PDF form to work with the Preview application, it should be enough if you avoid using XFA forms (usually PDF forms generated by Adobe LiveCycle) and embedded javascript code inside your PDF files. PDF forms using action buttons like "Clear Form", "Print" and "Submit" for example will always involve some javascript code.

Recommendations for libraries that allow you to create these forms will depend on the OS that you want to use for creating them, the programming language, etc. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210029/pdf-libraries) seems to have an extensive list o such libraries.